# Disable sorting in header column of Yii CGridView

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components, yii-events

Yii provides sorting functionality for listing. How can I disable sorting so that my records will not get sorted when clicked on column header?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

set  `'enableSorting' => false`  in your list/gridview definition.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        ......
        'enableSorting' => false,
        ......
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When Bootstrap is used you can disable sorting by using below syntax -

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView',
  array(
         ......
         'enableSorting' => false, //tag for sorting - true or false
         .........
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [GridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html)

Then you can do that:

```
$dataProvider =  new yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
        'sort'=>false,
    'query' => **some query here**
]);
```

or if you want to sort certain columns:

```
$dataProvider =  new yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
            'sort'=>['attribute'=>[**attribute names here**]],
        'query' => **some query here**
    ]);
```

and then use this *data provider* in your `GridView` widget:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
     'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
      ...
]) ?>
```